# How do I change mac before network service starts

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a systemd service that change mac address to wifi adapter every boot. Systemd service works fine. I want the service not wait 1m 30sec when the wifi adapter is not plug in the usb.

systemd service (macspoof@wlan0.service) load very early at boot...Before=network-pre.target

My goal is MAC is changed before a network managerNetworkManager service starts.

How can I do that?

```
[Unit]
Description=macchanger on %I
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -r %I
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ExecStart=` and write a simple wrapper script:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/macwrapper -r %I
```

and, in `/usr/local/bin/macwrapper`, something like (**UNTESTED!**):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set dev to your device name
dev="/dev/wifi"
# assume success
xit=0
if [[ -e "$dev" ]] ; then
    /usr/bin/macchanger $1 $2
    xit=$?
else
    logger -t macwrapper "MAC Not changed no device $dev"
# Don't save logger's status, don't  care
fi
exit $xit
```

Read `man bash test logger`.

Comment: I change to wlan0, but it doesn't work. there is no error message. only this logger -t macwrapper "MAC Not changed no device $dev"

Comment: Then delete the 'else` clause,  and it will run `macchanger` if `⁷$dev` exists, and does nothing if not. If you're looking to have `macchanger` run when you insert the device later, you're in the wrong place, `udev` handles device insertions. `man udev;man -k udev` and search `udev` here and elsewhere.

Comment: What do you get for `%I` when no device is connected? Disconnect the device; temporarily insert `printf "/$1/$2/\n" >/tmp/macwrapper.txt` just before the `macchanger` line. Then, restart `sudo shutdown -r now`. Inspect the file. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: I edited your answer with my changes. It doesn't work. I don't understand everything you said. Where can I write printf ??? in python???

Comment: It's a `bash` script. Put the `printf` just after `xit=0`.

Comment: Nothing! Inside macwrapper.txt has only `///` I tested with plug in wifi adapter and plug out.

Comment: waltinator Please can you help ?

Comment: There’s nothing in `/dev` that corresponds to network devices, so this won’t work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Make use of `ConditionPathExists=` or `ConditionPathExistsGlob=` in your service file, so it is skipped when the wifi adapter is not plugged into the usb port.
2. Make use of a `*.path` unit, and enable it, to activate the service when the wifi adapter is plugged into the usb port, instead of enabling the service unit itself.
3. A combination of the above.

Comment: I put `ConditionPathExists=!/sys/class/net/wlan0` without result.

Comment: It doesnt work `ConditionPathExists=!/sys/dev/char/134:122/2-4.3:1.0/net/wlan0` NOTHING

Comment: `=!` means does not... Don't you need to check for existence instead of non-existence? Checking for existence will make it only run when the file is available and skip the unit when not available...

Comment: Triplle the same. It doesn't work. Do you know if need differet path???? 2 paths in my example above are exist.

Comment: ℹ️You need to use a path that doesn't exist when the usb adapter is not connected, but DOES exist when it IS connected. I don't have your hardware so i can't tell you which path to use. Check with `journalctl -f`  to see what is logged when you plug the device in and out...

Comment: Triple this path `/sys/class/net/wlan0` doesn exist if usb wifi adapter is not plug in or connected.